# How to make an image non clickable

Tags: javascript

I have a java script clock in my webpage but i want to make it non clickable. 
I tried onclick= return false. May be im doing it wrong but am not able to get it to work.

```
<div align="center" style="margin:15px 0px 0px 0px">
    <div align="center" style="width:140px;solid #ccc;color: #fff ;font-weight:bold">
        <a style="padding:px 1px;margin:2px 1px;font-size:12px;line-height:16px;font-family:arial;text-decoration:none;color:#000" border=0 style="border:0;margin:0;padding:0">&nbsp;MST</a>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localtimes.info/clock.php?continent=North America&country=United States&province=Colorado&city=Denver&widget_number=121&fwdt=150&ham=1&hfg=1"></script>
</div>
```

Comment: You must post more code than that.

Comment: What exactlx do you mean with "non clickable". What bad things happen when the user clicks on it and what do you want to happen instead?

Comment: What does "nonclickable" mean? Please be more specific.

Comment: Thank You so much,that was quick.By non clickable i mean if a user clicks on the clock, it should not re direct user to an external website, which it does right now as u can see in the code it has the source to a diffrnt website.

Comment: @user2515101 The script seems to load a flash animation which then seems to do the redirection. So it's not javascript, it's flash.

Comment: Yes, It loads a flash animated clock.but it has an external link which i want to remove.But if the link is removed, clock will not work. so i thought of making it non clickable

Comment: I don't think you can make it "non-clickable".  The flash file is what you are clicking on, not the `<a>` tag.  So, unless the flash file has an API for you to use, there's nothing you can do.

Answer (score 0):

First, when you ask a question it's always good practice (and very appreciated!) showing some example code, in order to explain better the problem.

Secondly, **inline Javascript is bad**, and should be avoided! Take a look at [this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/86589/why-should-i-avoid-inline-scripting) on Stackexchange to comprehend why.

Preventing clicks in JS is easy, and the best solution it's usually using `event.preventDefault()`, example (with jQuery):

```
$('#your-clock').on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
});
```